# SonarQube - configuration of sonar-project.properties of a Java EE 6 project to get rid of WARN - Class not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, sonarqube, java-ee-6, sonarqube-4.5

I'm trying to analyse a huge Java EE 6 project. Due to the given ruleset with some older rules we're bound to Sonarqube 4.5.6 with some special plug-ins at the moment (analysis runs with Sonar Scanner 2.5.1).

The analysis of the project finishes without failing, but there are many warnings in the log about classes which weren't found like

```
WARN  - Class not found: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

Similar warnings from other plugins are also reported. So I looked around and found a workaround by adding the path to the Java EE 6 .jars to the `sonar.java.libraries` config in the `sonar-project.properties` file. Now, I got rid of the warings (except few classes in `org.apache.commons.io` and `org.apache.commons.fileupload` - whereever the corresponding .jar may be).

This will work on my local machine, but the *real* sonar server is somewhere else, where no Java EE 6 is present. So, I'd thought of copying the relevant .jars in some directory there and reference the directory in the `sonar.java.libraries`.

My problem: how to find out which .jars are actually used by the sonar analysis? I don't want to copy thousands of files when actually just maybe ten are needed.

Is there some hidden log file written by sonarqube or something similar? Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning comes from the java analyzer telling you that some .class files could not be found. What you describe as a workaround is the correct solution to get more precise result from your analysis.

Your question is : where can I find the jar corresponding to the classes warned as missing  ?

SonarQube java analyzer can't tell you that (because if it could, then it would try to find the classes). I would recommend you to lookup in http://www.findjar.com/ some classnames and see which dependency jars are required and add them sparsly.

Comment: Thanks. In my Eclipse-based environment, it turned out to be most efficient to use Open Type (shift-ctrl-T) and search for the missing class there - it will show the corresponding .jar that I then can include in my properties file - this way I found my handful of .jars I needed